# How to match an array in order with intervening elements using a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with an array of events objects :

```
  {
    "events": [
      {
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "C"
      },
      {
        "name": "D"
      },
      {
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "name": "E"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "events": [
      {
        "name": "A"
      },
      {
        "name": "B"
      },
      {
        "name": "S"
      },
      {
        "name": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this array, I want to count the number of events that are in a said order, with intervening events. For example, I look for the order [A,B,C], with the array [A,x,x,B,x], I should count 2, with [A,B,x,x,C] I should have 3. (x is just a placeholder for anything else)

I want to summarize this information for all my documents in the shape of an array, with the number of matches for each element. With the previous example that would give me [2,2,1], 2 matches for A, 2 matches for B, 1 match for C.

My Current aggregation is generated in javascript and follow this pattern :

- Match documents with the event array containing A
- Slice the array from A to the end of the array
- Count the number of documents
- Append the count of matching document to the summarizing array
- Match documents with the event array containing B
- Slice the array from B to the end of the array
- Count the number of documents
- etc

However, when an event does not appear in any of the arrays, it falls shorts,  as there are no documents, I do not have a way to store the summarizing array. For example, with the events array [A,x,x,B,x]  [A,B,x,x,C] and trying to match [A,B,D], I would expect [2,2,0], but I have [] as when trying to match D nothing comes up, and the aggregation cannot continue.

Here is the aggregation I'm working with : https://mongoplayground.net/p/rEdQD4FbyC4
change the matching letter l.75 to something not in the array to have the problematic behavior.

So is there a way to not lose my data when there is no match? like bypassing aggregation stages, I could not find anything related to bypassing stages in the mongoDB documentation.

Or are you aware of another way of doing this?

Comment: What if you try to match `[A, B, C, D]` with `[A, C, x, D, B, x, x]` ?

Comment: In that case I should only match [A, B]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended using a reduce to solve our problem

The reduce is on the events array and with every event we try to match it with the  element in sequence at the position "size of the accumulator", if it is a match it's added to the accumulator, ortherwise no, etc

here is the mongo playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/ge4nlFWuLsZ\

- The sequence we want to match is in the field "sequence"
- The matched elements are in the "matching" field